# Save parent child relationship from JSON using MagicalRecord

Tags: objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

I am reading from a local JSON file which has the following relationship

`Country -< Venues`

The JSON file contains all the countries as parents, then the venues as children as per the following example:

```
// Sample JSON (Countries have many venues)
    [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "USA",
        "venues": [
            {
                "venue": "Von Braun Center",
                "city" : "Huntsville",
                "state": "Alabama",
                "capacity": 13760
            }
        ]
    }];
```

The problem I am having is I would like to save the entities and relationships using MagicalRecord but it keeps complaining of an invalid context.

```
// Read through a JSON file then save to Core Data
        [MagicalRecord saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *c) {
            Country *country = [Country createInContext:c];
            [country setName:name];
        } completion:^{

            for (NSDictionary *venueData in venues) {

                NSString *venue = (NSString *) [venueData objectForKey:@"venue"];
                NSString *city = (NSString *) [venueData objectForKey:@"city"];
                NSString *state = (NSString *) [venueData objectForKey:@"state"];

                Venue *v = [Venue createEntity];
                v.name = venue;
                v.city = city;
                v.state = state;
                v.country = country;

            } // next

            [[NSManagedObjectContext defaultContext] saveNestedContexts];
        }];
```

I need to save the `country` first but then I cannot use it in the second part where I set a venue to a country.

My questions are:

1. How do I save the country and create/save a relationship using MagicalRecord between the country and the venue object
2. How do I make my country object work in the completion block.

Many thanks

---

Following advice from SO members, I've been able to solve the problem by putting it into one block;

```
for (NSDictionary *dict in json) {
                NSString *name = (NSString *) [dict objectForKey:@"name"];
                NSArray *venueList = (NSArray *) [dict valueForKey:@"venues"];

                [MagicalRecord saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *c) {
                    Country *country = [Country createInContext:c];
                    [country setName:name];

                    for (NSDictionary *venueData in venueList) {

                        NSString *name = (NSString *) [venueData objectForKey:@"venue"];
                        NSString *city = (NSString *) [venueData objectForKey:@"city"];
                        NSString *state = (NSString *) [venueData objectForKey:@"state"];
                        //NSNumber *capacity = (NSNumber *) [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[venueData valueForKey:@"capacity"] intValue]];

                        Venue *v = [Venue createInContext:c];
                        [v setName:name];
                        [v setCity:city];
                        [v setState:state];
                        [v setCountry:country];
                    } // next

                } completion:^{
                }];
            } // next
```

Many thanks to all those that helped

Comment: Why do you need to save the country first?

Comment: Because a country has many venues.  I need to have the country defined and exist before I can create any venues.

Comment: Why. You just iterate the venues and add them all. If you were batching then maybe but then you would already have your country available.

Comment: I thought I had to make an object exist before I could use it, but I will try to add them in the same block as per @casademora

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do everything in the first save block, forget about the completion block. It's ok to do just one save in this case, and then you won't have to worry about creating objects in the wrong context.

Comment: Okay, I will try this.  I've not done this before and I thought I had to do one bit at a time

Comment: Note that in your original you weren't doing each venue one at a time. The only requirement is that what you save is valid and consistent.